# Qual a diferença entre instanciar na mesma variável ou em 3 variáveis diferentes?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, groovy, instanciar-objeto

Segue parte um:

```
class Pessoa{

    String firstName
    String lastName
    int age
    def address

    static main(args) {
      def p = new Pessoa()

      p.setFirstName("Lars")

      p.lastName = "Vogel"
      p.address = "Homestreet 3"
      println(p.firstName + " " + p.lastName);

      println ""


      p = new Pessoa(firstName: "Peter", lastName:"Mueller");
      println(p.firstName + " " + p.lastName);

      println ""

      p = new Pessoa(firstName: "Aline", lastName: "Gonzaga")

      println (p.firstName+" "+ p.lastName)
}
```

Segue parte dois:

```
class Pessoa{

    String firstName
    String lastName
    int age
    def address

    static main(args) {
      def p = new Pessoa()

      p.setFirstName("Lars")

      p.lastName = "Vogel"
      p.address = "Homestreet 3"
      println(p.firstName + " " + p.lastName);

      println ""


     def p1 = new Pessoa(firstName: "Peter", lastName:"Mueller");
      println(p1.firstName + " " + p1.lastName);

      println ""

     def p2 = new Pessoa(firstName: "Aline", lastName: "Gonzaga")

      println (p2.firstName+" "+ p2.lastName)
}
```

A minha dúvida seria em `p1` e `p2` do segundo exemplo. Por que existem essas duas formas de instanciar? Qual a melhor opção para fazer isso? Me explique por que a primeira forma é daquele jeito e a segunda é do outro jeito. Tem a ver com performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Precisaria ver o contexto. parecem ser exemplos mostrando diversas formas de uso do objeto.

Acredito que esteja apenas demonstrando no primeiro como usar a mesma variáveis para armazenar objetos diferentes - não ao mesmo tempo, um sobrepõe o outro. Ou seja, há apenas um dado que tem seu valor trocado (com nova identidade). Isso é o mesmo que dizer `x=1` e depois  dizer `x = 2`.

Já o segundo mostra que os objetos podem ser armazenados  em variáveis diferentes, portanto mantendo seu estado em cada uma delas. Há 3 dados diferentes. É o mesmo que dizer `x = 1` e `y = 2`, são duas coisas diferentes.

Nada a ver com performance. Depende do que quer. Eu entendo que estes exemplos artificiais muitas vezes mais confundem do que ajudam.

Se tivesse mais contexto eu poderia achar outra explicação, mas duvido que fuja disto.

Faça este exemplo que talvez fique mais óbvio a mudança:

```
class Pessoa {
    String firstName
    String lastName
    int age
    def address
    
    static main(args) {
      def p = new Pessoa()
      p.setFirstName("Lars")
      p.lastName = "Vogel"
      p.address = "Homestreet 3"
      p = new Pessoa(firstName: "Peter", lastName:"Mueller");
      p = new Pessoa(firstName: "Aline", lastName: "Gonzaga")
      println(p.firstName + " " + p.lastName);
      println ""
      println(p.firstName + " " + p.lastName);
      println ""
      println (p.firstName+" "+ p.lastName)
}
```

Segue parte dois:

```
class Pessoa {
    String firstName
    String lastName
    int age
    def address
    
    static main(args) {
      def p = new Pessoa()
      p.setFirstName("Lars")
      p.lastName = "Vogel"
      p.address = "Homestreet 3"
      def p1 = new Pessoa(firstName: "Peter", lastName:"Mueller");
      def p2 = new Pessoa(firstName: "Aline", lastName: "Gonzaga")
      println(p.firstName + " " + p.lastName);
      println ""
      println(p1.firstName + " " + p1.lastName);
      println ""
      println (p2.firstName+" "+ p2.lastName)
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Class.groovy).

Agora está fazendo as 3 impressões depois de instanciar os objetos. Como no primeiro exemplo um objeto sobrepõe o outro no fundo a as 3 impressões só imprimem o resultado final. No segundo exemplo, como os dados ficam preservados em 3 variáveis diferentes, eles podem ser impressos independentemente em qualquer momento que estas variáveis ainda estejam ativas.

Este tipo de construção só serve para exemplo, em código real ninguém faz isto. Principalmente colocar o `main()` dentro da classe `Pessoas`.

Comment: Lars Vogel

Peter Mueller

Aline Gonzaga
Isso é impresso. as duas formas imprimem iguais, como pode uma sobrepor a outra? , essa parte de estado como assim?  Não entendi...

Comment: A variável `p` está armazenando o `Lars`, depois ela passa armazenar o `Peter` e depois ela passa armazenar a `Aline`. É como você dizer `x = 1` e depois dizer `x = 2`. É simples assim.

Comment: mas e quanto a impressão? 
Lars Vogel Peter Mueller Aline Gonzaga
Não tenho uma variável imprimindo um nome só.

Comment: Você não sabe nada de programação então? Ele está mandando imprimir os nomes das pessoas. Não sei qual é a dúvida. Vou por exemplo que ajuda entender o uso das variáveis.

Comment: Se x=1 e depois x=2 não iria imprimir 2?

Comment: Acho que entendi, o segredo está na posição do println.

Comment: Se eu fizer x = 1
println x
x=2
println x

Imprime 1 e 2. : )

Comment: Isso mesmo. A programação segue um fluxo. A ordem é fundamental. Esta é a base de todo código.

Comment: certo! Entendi.

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que seu exemplo foi feito para exemplificar diversas maneiras de se construir uma instância.

Quando você instância um objeto, é invocado automaticamente um método construtor, que não foi declarado. Se você instanciar um objeto com Pessoa(); será invocado o método construtor pessoa(); que irá apenas inicializar as variáveis com valores vazios.

Já ao instanciar com Pessoa(firstName: "Peter"); você invoca um método construtor que aceite um parâmetro.

Você pode controlar isto ao declarar um método construtor e especificar qual serão suas entradas, desta forma, você tratará as informações que chegarem.

por exemplo declarar `pessoa(){ ......}` ou `pessoa(String firstName){.....}`  desta forma, na hora que o objeto é instanciado, a própria linguagem identifica qual dos dois métodos construtores será chamado, baseado no tipo de parâmetro fornecido.